# Configure separate port for Jboss Admin Console

Tags: jboss5.x, firewall, system-administration

We want to configure our jboss server behind a firewall. We want to allow public access only to our web application not for any standard JBoss service like admin console jmx console.

Is there any way to configure separate port for jboss **admin-console, jmx-console**?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand with pure JBOSS - nope. JBOSS have only one connector and one deployment facility for web-applications.

However, If you use Apache before JBOSS it's very easy:  for myself - I solved the problem using apache mod_jk. and publishing admin-console, jmx-console using separate VirtualHost and JkMount:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:443>
   JkMount /admin-console/* jbossServer
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost public.com:80>
    JkMount /public-application/* jbossServer
    JkMount /another-public-application/* jbossServer
</VirtualHost>
```

However in this case you'll be obligated to update your apache configs, when deploying new applications.

Comment: @llya Dyoshin, Thanks for your information. Currently I am using this solution. Is there any way to deploy those wars separately as web-service deployments. Is there any way to clone jbossweb.sar and use it(I tried but failed)?